# Robolectric 3.0 - Resource not resolved when using applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have been sucessfully using this code to load resources both in an app and its unit tests with Robolectric 2.4:

```
getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "string", getContext().getPackageName());
```

where Context would be MyApplication in the App and TestMyApplication in Robolectric tests.

With Robolectric 3.0 this no longer works when an applicationIdSuffix is added to the build file, the call returns 0.

Is this a known issue? This is on com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.0-beta1 and org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2

**Update** https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1623

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is actually a simple fix for this now, just add `@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, packageName = com.your.package)`

See https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples/tree/master/android-flavors

Comment: Note that you can set global properties in a robolectric.properties file that's in your test classpath. For example, for tests in src/test, I created a src/test/resources/robolectric.properties file with the values below. If you _also_ use the @Config annotation, I believe this completely overrides the global properties file for the associated tests; it doesn't layer local values over global values. [Configuration Info](http://robolectric.org/configuring/) - Sample robolectric.properties (one per line): `sdk=21` `packageName=com.your.package.name` 
`constants=com.your.package.name.BuildConfig`

Comment: Error: **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b0020**

Answer (score 1):

As workaround I created another build flavour `jenkins` where I removed suffix editing. Unfortunately it is not proper solution if you want to test something specific/customised for flavour.

Comment: Thats kind of my problem, I need to be able to test multiple build variants.

Answer (score 0):

For Robolectric 3.0 you should probably use the `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` instead of the basic `RobolectricTestRunner`.  This test runner allows you to specify all the details specific to a build variant with a constant class.  For your specific case, **it also allows the specification of a proper applicationId**.  This should get you around the issue your having with the *applicationIdSuffix* for your tests.

Usage is as follows:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(emulateSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT,
    constants = SomeTestClass.BuildConfig.class)
public class SomeTestClass {
    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception {
        String s = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

        assert(s).equals("Some Debug Name"); // <-- defined in src/debug/res/values/strings.xml
    }

    public static class BuildConfig {
        public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.some.company.special";
        public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
        public static final String FLAVOR = "";
    }
}
```

There are a couple of key things here to note:

1. We're running with the Gradle specific test runner `@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)`
2. We're configuring this test to use specific application configurations via the `constants` property in the `@Config` block. The empty string for `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` is for when there is no specific simple or compound flavor.
3. The `APPLICATION_ID` specified in the `BuildConfig` class should match applicationId you have specified for the build variant in your build.gradle file.
4. We're counting on the android-gradle plugin to properly merge all of our resources for the particular build variant.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately this results in `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Robolectric does not support API level 1.
 at org.robolectric.internal.SdkConfig.<init>(SdkConfig.java:28)` when I run a test.

Comment: Add a config block before the test suite `@Config(emulateSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)` or whatever version of Android you're trying to emulate.

Comment: Thanks, I should probably have RTFM :) Now the test runs, but the underlying issue still persists.

Comment: **RobolectricGradleTestRunner** is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

with applicationIdSuffix the generated BuildConfig will use a package name with the suffix, this doesn't work under Robolectric 3.0.

My solution is creating a subclass of RobolectricGradleTestRunner and "override" the getPackageName() function (cannot override it directly, it's private static) to return the hard coded package name without the suffix.

Comment: I would argue that setting the packageName via the @Config annotation or a global robolectric.properties file is simpler and cleaner. See answer by Philipp E., along with my comment on a properties file.